# Creating a single file from multiple streams while keeping the streams and files order with Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

I have a Gulp task where I would like to compile HTML templates to javascript (lets say from `/views` directory), add all other javascript sources to this (from `/js` directory) and concatenate all of them into one single file.

**Its also important to have the files concatenated in the correct order**, meaning: all files from `/js` then all compiled files from `/views`.

My goal is to avoid creating temporary files in general, so the solution I seek only works with streams.

This task currently works **without correctly ordering** the output:

```
var eventstream = require('event-stream');
gulp.task('dist', function()
{
    return eventstream.merge(
        gulp.src(['**/[^_]*.js', '!**/_*/**'], { cwd: 'js' })
    ,
        gulp.src(['**/[^_]*.html', '!**/_*/**'], { cwd: 'views' })
        .pipe(compile_views())
    )
    .pipe(concat('output.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Tried a few stream merging modules from NPM with less success, all of them scrambled my output so far:

- multistream
- stream-series
- merge-stream
- ordered-merge-stream

Also tried using the `gulp-order` plugin after merging the streams, which still does not ordered it correctly.

Did I miss something, or am I doing something the bad way? I'm not so expert in pipes yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`streamqueue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamqueue) is what you're looking for:

```
var streamqueue = require('streamqueue');

gulp.task('dist', function() {
  return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
    gulp.src(['**/[^_]*.js', '!**/_*/**'], { cwd: 'js' }),
    gulp.src(['**/[^_]*.html', '!**/_*/**'], { cwd: 'views' })
      .pipe(compile_views())
  )
  .pipe(concat('output.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I looked for!